# Need help connecting to libera chat

Tags: irc

I am having trouble connecting to libera.chat and irc.libera.chat using Konversation Version 1.8.21123 on Jammy Jellyfish (fully updated). I have worked through the steps given on https://userbase.kde.org/Konversatio...tication#step5 and still cannot connect. The repeating log is shown below.

```
[12:44] [Info] Looking for server irc.libera.chat (port 6697)...
[12:44] [Info] Server found, connecting...
[12:44] [Info] Negotiating capabilities with server...
[12:44] [Notice] -lithium.libera.chat- *** Checking Ident
[12:44] [Notice] -lithium.libera.chat- *** Looking up your hostname...
[12:44] [Notice] -lithium.libera.chat- *** Couldn't look up your hostname
[12:45] [Notice] -lithium.libera.chat- *** No Ident response
[12:45] [Capabilities] account-notify away-notify chghost extended-join multi-prefix sasl=PLAIN,ECDSA-NIST256P-CHALLENGE,EXTERNAL tls account-tag cap-notify echo-message server-time solanum.chat/identify-msg solanum.chat/oper solanum.chat/realhost
[12:45] [Info] Requesting capabilities: account-notify away-notify chghost extended-join multi-prefix sasl cap-notify server-time
[12:45] [Info] SASL capability acknowledged by server, attempting SASL PLAIN authentication...
[12:45] [Error] SASL authentication attempt failed.
[12:45] [Info] Closing capabilities negotiation.
[12:45] [Error] Connection to server irc.libera.chat (port 6697) lost: The TLS/SSL connection has been closed.
[12:45] [Info] Trying to reconnect to irc.libera.chat (port 6697) in 10 seconds.
[12:45] [Info] Looking for server irc.libera.chat (port 6697)...​ <-- Log repeats from this line.
```

Is there something blatant that I have overlooked ?

Is there some web page that I need to visit in order to register my ident/hostname/whatever (!) ?

Stuart
​

Comment: it might be helpful if you decided to share your SASL config for libera. just a thought.

Answer (score -1):

Well your log says that your client is trying to do SASL but it fails.

I would look at your config for libera and see why. besides that please look at this guide provided by libere:

[using SASL](https://libera.chat/guides/sasl)